# Mouse click not working in my column chart in html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi all again i have problem in my chart construction in html 5. This time did everything well except one part or module. I tried some code which i got through internet for displaying some alert when a rectangle in canvas in clicked. When i comment the module it works fine but not the mouse click. Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance. Here is my fiddle and code [fiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/s8kZs/

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function() {
                var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
                var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
                var graphInfo=[{data:[120,130,140,160,180,100],color:'purple',label:["a","b","c","d","e","f"]},{data:[100,120,130,140,150,190],color:'green',label:["g","h","i","j","k","l"]}];
                var width=45;
                 function renderGrid(gridPixelSize, color)
        {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            for(var i = 20; i <= canvas.height-20; i = i + gridPixelSize)
            {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(20, i);
                ctx.lineTo(canvas.width-20, i);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            for(var j = 20; j <= canvas.width-20; j = j + gridPixelSize)
            {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(j, 20);
                ctx.lineTo(j, canvas.height-20);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            ctx.restore();
        }
       renderGrid(10, "grey");

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.moveTo(20, canvas.height-20);
                ctx.lineTo(canvas.width-20, canvas.height-20);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();

                ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
                ctx.lineTo(20, canvas.height-20);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";

        function getFunctionForTimeout(j){
                    var i=0,currx=30,info=graphInfo[j],x5=j*5;
                    var fTimeout=function(){
                        var h=Math.max(info.data[i]-x5,0);
                        var m=info.label[i];
                        ctx.fillStyle='black'
                        ctx.fillRect(currx+(10*x5)+2,canvas.height-h-20,width+2,h-1);
                        ctx.fillStyle=info.color;                   
                        ctx.fillRect(currx+(10*x5),canvas.height-h-21,width,h);                 
                        ctx.fillText(m, currx+(10*x5)+20, canvas.height-5);
                        currx+=120;  
                        i++;
                        /*var ctx = $('#mycanvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
                        $('#mycanvas').click(function(e) {
        var x = e.offsetX,
            y = e.offsetY;

        for(var k=0;k<j;k++) {
            if(x > currx+(10*x5)
            && x < canvas.height-h-21
            && y > width
            && y < h) {
                alert('Rectangle ' + j + ' clicked');
            }
        }
    });*/
                        if(i<info.data.length)setTimeout(fTimeout,2000);
                    };
                    return fTimeout;
        }

                for(var j=graphInfo.length-1;j>=0;j--) {
                    setTimeout(getFunctionForTimeout(j),2000);
                }
            };
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <canvas id="mycanvas" height="400" width="800" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is some issue in the if condition you are checking for alerting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for giving you mouse position where you are clicking on the canvas, i just altered your code for correcting it for the alert you are expecting but there is some issue in your condition which you generate as an alert.

Njoy clicking and alerting the mouse position; if you want the same alert you expect, alter your if condition you will get it by my position alert...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function() {
            var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
            var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
            var graphInfo=[{data:[120,130,140,160,180,100],color:'purple',label:["a","b","c","d","e","f"]},{data:[100,120,130,140,150,190],color:'green',label:["g","h","i","j","k","l"]}];
            var width=45;
            function renderGrid(gridPixelSize, color)
            {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
                ctx.strokeStyle = color;
                for(var i = 20; i <= canvas.height-20; i = i + gridPixelSize)
                {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(20, i);
                    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width-20, i);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                for(var j = 20; j <= canvas.width-20; j = j + gridPixelSize)
                {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(j, 20);
                    ctx.lineTo(j, canvas.height-20);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                ctx.restore();
            }
               renderGrid(10, "grey");

                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                        ctx.moveTo(20, canvas.height-20);
                        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width-20, canvas.height-20);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.stroke();

                        ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                        ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
                        ctx.lineTo(20, canvas.height-20);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";

            function getFunctionForTimeout(j){
                var i=0,currx=30,info=graphInfo[j],x5=j*5;
                var fTimeout=function(){
                    var h=Math.max(info.data[i]-x5,0);
                    var m=info.label[i];
                    var ctx = $('#mycanvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
                    ctx.fillStyle='black'
                    ctx.fillRect(currx+(10*x5)+2,canvas.height-h-20,width+2,h-1);
                    ctx.fillStyle=info.color;                    
                    ctx.fillRect(currx+(10*x5),canvas.height-h-21,width,h);                    
                    ctx.fillText(m, currx+(10*x5)+20, canvas.height-5);
                    currx+=120;  
                    i++;

                    $('#mycanvas').click(function(e) {
                        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
                        var message = "Mouse position: " + mousePos.x + "," + mousePos.y;
                        var x = mousePos.x;
                        var y = mousePos.y;
                        alert(message);

                        for(var k=0;k<j;k++) {
                            if(x > currx+(10*x5)
                            && x < canvas.height-h-21
                            && y > width
                            && y < h) {
                                alert('Rectangle ' + j + ' clicked');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if(i<info.data.length)setTimeout(fTimeout,2000);
                };
                return fTimeout;
            }       

            for(var j=graphInfo.length-1;j>=0;j--) {
                setTimeout(getFunctionForTimeout(j),2000);
            }
            function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
                var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), root = document.documentElement;

            // return relative mouse position
            var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
            var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
                return {
                  x: mouseX,
                  y: mouseY
                };
              }
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" height="400" width="800" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </body>
</html>
```

Just check the change in getMousePos() for the same u needed

Cheers!!! Njoy!!!

Comment: var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), root = document.documentElement;

    // return relative mouse position
    var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;

Comment: Just check the change in getMousePos() for the same u needed

Comment: Thanks for ur interest on my question. It helped a lot and hope i can achieve my goal with it. Now am concentrating on my another problem. i am posting it as a new question. Wish u can help on that too